# List specific Dropbox folder with Dropbox API in PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to list all files and directories from a specific path (recursivelly) with the Dropbox API?

E.g. I want to list all files which are stored in `Projects/Customers/CustomerXY/` of my account statically on my website.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick look at the **Core Dropbox API** it seems this is possible using the `/metadata` endpoint.

Take a look at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata, you can use the information provided to create a recursive function or just display the files/folders within the specified folder.

Comment: The best practices (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/bestpractice ) advise against doing this recursively. You could use /delta ( https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta ) to get the whole state and filter as necessary though.

Comment: Good point, they should really provide a more effective endpoint then to support this.